# DynDNS alongside Tor?

Tags: dns, tor

Is there a way to resolve Dynamic DNS with Tor so that I can connect to my computer behind a NAT even if I am in a country that consider supicious connections to my native country ?

Answer (score 0):

DynDNS does not differ from standard DNS in any way.

The issue with Tor is that it only handles TCP, while DNS query usually relies on UDP protocol. Due to this, without further precaution, DNS resolution queries will be sent outside of the Tor tunnel.

You should therefore use a specific distribution, like [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Tor_enforcement/DNS/) or [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Main_Page), which will ensure that all your traffic including DNS queries will be sent through Tor (these are live-systems, you can boot your computer from them or use them inside a virtual machine).